# Non-singularity of $C=A-B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

$A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices and I am looking for a condition such that $C$ is non-singular. 
Can I say by Weyl's inequality that $\lambda(C)_{min}>=\lambda(A)_{min}$-$\lambda(B)_{max}$ and I somehow have that $\lambda(A)_{min}-\lambda(B)_{max}>0$ then the matrix $C$ is invertible.

P.S. If true, is there any other way to get an invertible $C$?
Perhaps a weaker condition on eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ such that $C$ is invertible.

Comment: Yes, the statement is true, and you don't need a result as strong as Weyl's inequalities.  The question "is there any other way to get an invertible $C$" is too vague to be answered usefully

Comment: Thanks, so what weaker condition do you suggest?

Comment: Also I didn't think to ask: are the eigenvalues of $A$ non-negative? If not, you should clarify what you mean by "min" and "max".

Comment: There is no weaker assumption on the eigenvalues that will work since your inequality is strict

Comment: No the eigenvalues of A can be positive or negative. I meant by ordering the eigenvalues $\lambda_1>\lambda_2>....>\lambda_n$ where $\lambda_1$ is $\lambda_{max}$.

Comment: In other words, *not* in terms of absolute value. So yes your statement as written is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation!